# How does Firebug get the source code of a page which has a ajax call and is that file saved somewhere?

Tags: ajax, firebug, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape information from a site where the relevant information is continuously updated using Ajax calls . Inspite of repeated attempts, I haven't been able to determine the link from which the ajax calls are receiving data . So , I decided to change track and use firebug to get the data since it is showing me the data got from the Ajax call. So, does Firebug save the page source anywhere and can we access that by any chance?

[This](http://www.gaana.com/#!/radiostations/meethi-mirchi) is the link and I am trying to get the song + movie name from the bottom of the page which is updated using Ajax calls. I have tried going through the firebug source code to determine the save but that has also not yielded any result.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did find the solution to my problem . Looking under Net tab in firebug, I was able to find out the ajax call that was editing the particular site. Using the response I finally managed to use urllib and urllib2 to get the required data :).

As for how firebug gets the source code , there were a few links that I read which said that Firebug gets the exact source code at that instant because it is a browser extension and so has more access to the browser variables and the server response. But not sure how correct the information is.

Cheers